# Routers and Menu Items

Tags: joomla, routes

Remove joomla menu alias from the route. Is it possible to remove menu alias from joomla component (router.php) file? If is it possible please provide an example.
Thanks!

P.S I have read this article: http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component
(Routers and Menu Items) but how to find an example of this kind of router helper?

Comment: I've read in that link that you should write your own function [componentname]RouteHelper that will try to find the most suitable route and they provide examples where there isn't included menu's alias inside your actual route, but they don't say how to implement this...

Answer (score 0):

Every Joomla component with front-end content has a router. Even the built-in ones, so you could look at the router file for `com_content` which provides and manages the `Article`'s.

You can find the Content router file at: `/components/com_content/router.php`

Comment: Your example does not remove menu alias. Thanks!